# Python curses print terminal color escape codes

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, curses, python-curses

I have a bash script that prints a nice big colorful table, using escape codes for foreground and background generated from `tput`.  My curses application needs to call this bash script and put the output on the screen.

When I try to do that, curses explodes with a stacktrace ending at:

```
File "./dostuff.py", line 38, in print_art
    screen.addstr(y, x_start, line)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Where "line" is something like:

`'\x1b[44m\x1b[30mcard           major  minor  revision  runs  updated\x1b(B\x1b[m\x1b(B\x1b[m\n'`

Is there any way to make curses interpret these color codes?  Any processing I could do to the string with the color codes to make curses display it?  Or do I have to basically remove color from the bash script and then reimplement the colorization in python?

EDIT:

The command that gets the bash output is something like:

```
print_art(subprocess.Popen(["./automount", "backup", "list"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])
```

By calling `decode()` on the byte string, I can get curses to print the strings, albeit with literal escape sequences.  Unless I hear from anyone else, I'm just going to parse these literal escape sequences manually and convert to use curses color methods.

Comment: As the error message says, It is not about color codes. `subprocess` uses `bytes` by default.  Usually you could pass `universal_newlines=True` to get output from the subprocess as a string but in this case you should probably find `curses` API that accepts `bytes` directly.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, there doesn't appear to be any curses API that accepts bytes.  However, I did make some progress and now have a (somewhat crappy) direction to go in, unless anyone else has another idea.  See my edit.

Comment: there is no need to decode manually. As I said, to get `str`, enable text mode: `text = subprocess.check_output(["./automount", "backup", "list"], universal_newlines=True)`. Also, `addstr()` accepts `bytes` on my machine on Python 3.4 (no type error). It won't help with color codes that are on a lower abstraction level than `curses` (you could something like `colorama` on Windows if there is no way to pass the codes transparently).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I always find `.decode("utf-8")` shorter and more transparent than `universal_newlines=True`. YMMV.

Comment: Yes, the name of the parameter is unfortunate (the way the meaning of the `universal_newlines` is overloaded in Python 3). But `.decode("utc-8")` is different. `universal_newlines=True`,  has the same effect as: `io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO(data)).read()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I do need to decode manually - if I use `decode()` or `universal_newlines`, curses will print the shell escape codes literally, so I have to strip these from the strings and apply the proper curses color arguments to the `addstr()` calls.

Comment: as I said twice already: the color codes issue is orthogonal to the text (Unicode) vs. binary (bytes) issue  (all color codes are ascii and therefore the shouldn't be any problems with encoding/decoding them in any ascii-based locale). For example, `addstr()` on my machine accepts both `str` and `bytes` types but it does not help (as expected) with handling of the ansi color codes. Again, look at `colorama` package and see how it translates ansi codes to Windows API calls: it may help you to estimate the amount of work required if you want to translate the codes into curses API calls.

Comment: See also the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/908440/500942) to "How to write binary data in stdout in python 3?"

Comment: Is this the same thing? http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ansi_escape_sequences.htm

Comment: @JGFMK Yes, the output I was asking about were ANSI color escape codes.

Comment: i think it's not about python or ncurse, but you terminal, some terminal does not recognize such color indicator ? consider state your system and terminal emulator

Comment: Read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037

Comment: Might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368796/how-to-create-scrollable-console-application-that-support-ansi-escape-code-seque

Comment: This answers your question: [ANSI colors in C and ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373690/ansi-colors-in-c-and-ncurses).

Comment: FWIW `universal_newlines=True` is now (since Python 3.7 IIRC) a legacy keyword argument which is still supported, but the preferred version is simply `text=True` which is both shorter and more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I tried copying code from network:

```
#!/bin/python
import curses
screen = curses.initscr()
screen.addstr(0, 0, "This string gets printed at position (0, 0)")
screen.addstr(3, 1, "Try Russian text:
")  # Python 3 required for unicode
screen.addstr(4, 4, "X")
line='\x1b[44m\x1b[30mcard           major  minor  revision  runs  updated\x1b(B\x1b[m\x1b(B\x1b[m\n'
y=10
x_start=5
print( type(x_start) )
print( type(y) )
screen.addstr( y, x_start, line)
screen.addch(5, 5, "Y")
screen.refresh()
curses.napms(3000)
curses.endwin()
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./dostuff.py
<class 'int'>
             <class 'int'>
This string gets printed at position (0, 0)


 Try Russian text: Привет
    X
     Y




     ^[[44m^[[30mcard           major  minor  revision  runs  updated^[(B^[[m^[(B^[[m
```

After few seconds updated output:

```
$ ./dostuff.py
<class 'int'>
             <class 'int'>
```

We can press Ctrl s and Ctrl q to stop current output at current terminal.
Hence check the type of following variables:

```
y
x_start
line
```

if any mismatch, start using something like:

```
str(y)
or
str(x_start)
or
str(line)
```

to handle those exception.